# LocalStorage and update the data on each input JS

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am trying to save the data into my object from input fileds using the `localStorage` but when I add a value into input and save it, it saves but when I try to add new value it deletes the old value and adds the new one instead. My demands are in the following :

- how to make it not replace the old entry and just take the new one?
- if I do render the data to html it shows me just what it is in the
  links obj it doesn't show me
- every entry should update the **links** obj  with new entry in
  `localStorage`.  how can I do that ?

here is the code : `JavaScript`:

```
let links = {
    team1: {
      icon: "FCL.png",
      list: [{ name: "Real Madrid", url: "www.Real Madrid.com" }]
    },
    team2: {
      icon: "FCL.png",
      list: [{ name: "FC Barcelona", url: "www.FCB.com" }]
    },
    fav: {
      icon: "fav.png",
      list: []
    }
  };
  $("#click").click(function () {
    const link = document.querySelector("#link").value;
    const name = document.querySelector("#name").value;
    links["fav"].list.push({ url: link, name: name });
    localStorage.setItem("links", JSON.stringify(links));
    console.log(localStorage.setItem("links", JSON.stringify(links)));
  });
```

HTML:

```
<form name="form1" action="">
      <input type="text" name="link" id="link" />
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
      <button id="click">click</button>
    </form>
```

here sandbox : [enter link description here](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-brown-qtqzm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the problem is when you are reloading web page, the `links` variable is getting the initial value you declared in your code. If you want to keep persisting the updating links, you need to first check if links already exists in `localStorage`, if so, then assign it to `links`or else set the default value.

Example:

```
const localStorageLinks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("links"))

let links = localStorageLinks || {
    team1: {
      icon: "FCL.png",
      list: [{ name: "Real Madrid", url: "www.Real Madrid.com" }]
    },
    team2: {
      icon: "FCL.png",
      list: [{ name: "FC barcelona", url: "www.FCL.com" }]
    },
    fav: {
      icon: "fav.png",
      list: []
    }
  };
```

Now, even if you reload the page your links will have the latest updated links.

Comment: ah thank you so much  Mohaimin ,so no if i want to call me links to render will save the new input too

Answer (score 0):

`setItem()` method will add the key to the given LocalStorage object, or update (replace) that key's value if it already exists.
If
You have to use `JSON.parse()` method parses a JSON string in LocalStorage, add the new value.

```
list = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("links") || [];
list.push({ url: link, name: name });
localStorage.setItem("links", JSON.stringify(links));
```